# Second order linear ODE $y^{\prime\prime}+\frac{2y^{\prime}}{x}-\frac{2y}{x^2}=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have $y^{\prime\prime}+\frac{2y^{\prime}}{x}-\frac{2y}{x^2}=0$

How do I solve this?

What have I tried?

$1)$ Coupled system:

$\begin{pmatrix}y_1^{\prime} \\ y_2^{\prime}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\frac{2}{x^2} & -\frac{2}{x^2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$

Then I want the eigen-values of $A$ above(from $y' =Ay$). $(-\lambda)(\frac{-2}{x^2}-\lambda)-\frac{2}{x^2}=0$,

$$\frac{2\lambda}{x^2}+\lambda^2 -\frac{2}{x^2}=0$$

(Which gets us to the same equation as you would get from the original ODE from simply exchanging the order of the derivative with a power)

$2)$ $y''+\frac{2y'}{x} - \frac{2y}{x^2}\Rightarrow\lambda^2+\frac{2\lambda}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x^2}=0$

Perhaps this was how the method was made? I don't know.

So here I have $\lambda = \cfrac{-4 \pm \sqrt{48}}{4x}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{3} - 1}{x}$

What does this mean my solution is? I have $x$ in my solution??

Comment: Try an $x^n$ ansatz. (To motivate that suggestion, note that each term of the ODE lowers the degree of a power of $x$ by two.)

Comment: Your ODE is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) after multiplying both sides by $x^2$. The above ansatz is mentioned on the Wikipedia article.

Comment: One could also solve your differential equation via the change of variable $t=\ln(x)$, as it converts your ODE to a second order linear homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute in: $$y=x^m$$
$$y'=mx^{m-1}$$
$$y''=m(m-1)x^{m-2}$$

into: $$x^2y^{\prime\prime}+2xy^{\prime}-2y=0$$
$$=m(m-1)x^{m}+2mx^{m}-2x^{m}=0$$
$$m(m-1)+2m-2=0$$
$$m^2-m+2m-2=0$$
$$m^2+m-2=0$$
$$(m+2)(m-1)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad m=-2,1$$
$$y=x^{-2},y=x$$
$$y=Ax+\frac{B}{x^2}$$

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you for teaching me all of it!!!